# How to route Vue Server to Node.js Backend

Tags: node.js, vue.js, config

how can i use Vue Dev Server with my node.js Server?
I'm currently doing it by creating a build from Vue with `npm run build` and copy the created ´dist´folder to my node backend.
And with the route

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
 res.sendFile(__dirname, 'index.html');
})
```

i can access to the index.html.
But i see any examples to serve the Vue server to the node server, in order not to create a build every time and copy the created ´/dist/ folder to the node.js Backend.

For Example it should be possible if change the `vue.config.js` file.

i have tried this config:

```
module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    proxy: {
      '^/api': {
        target: 'http://localhost:3080',
        changeOrigin: true
      },
    }
  }
}
```

But what should be in the `target` porberty?
My node.js is running on Port 443.
i also tried it with `'http://localhost:443'` or `https://<URL-FROM-Site>:443`.
Then start both server `node` and `vue` and treied to access the vue app with `https://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX:<PORT>/api`

With `https://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX:<PORT>/` i can access to my `node.js` and get the `index.html` file from the `dist` folder.

Comment: `npm run dev` creates a temporary development server that serves your files live over localhost.  You don't have to do anything other than run to command to run and access your site _while still developing_.  `npm run build` is for production where you move the static files to an actual web server (node, IIS, etc.).  If both frontend and backend are running on localhost you don't really need to set up a devServer `proxy` setting. It's more useful for if they're on different domains. Just use the full localhost + port URL of your backend when making axios or fetch calls.

Comment: OK, both are on the same machine, but i can start my vue frontend with `npm run serve`, so it can be loaded over `http://localhost:8080`. But my backend starts with `node app.js` and i can load my node server with the root like `app.get('/', (req, res) => {
 res.sendFile(__dirname, 'index.html');})` How can i serve the localhost from vue to my `root` api endpoint from my Node server? I hope i could explain my Problem. :)

Comment: I might not be fully understanding the problem.  For development purposes, the frontend and backend can run completely separately.  The `'/'` endpoint doesn't need to serve the frontend's index.html because it's serving itself on localhost:8080 via the webpack development server created by `npm run serve`.

Comment: Ok, i try to explain it better. In my Frontend is created with vue. So, in my Backend i have defined some CRUD operations like get, post, put and delete. I can start both separately from each other. Both server runnin on external machine. So i can normally create a build from my vue Frontend which creates a dist folder. This dist folder i can copy to te root from my backend in order to use my CRUD operations with my created vue app. The `/` endpoint routes to the index.html file, which is in the `dist` folder. So, how can i serve my `/` endpoint to the localhost:8080 from the vue app?

Comment: You don't need to.  Development builds don't need to be served by a separate web server.  Let webpack continue serving the app on `localhost:8080`.  Let your backend run on `localhost:3080`. Your CRUD endpoints can still be reached from the frontend by using the backend URL like `fetch('http://localhost:3080/api/someEndpoint)`.  You can use [.env variables](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html#modes) in place of hardcoded URLS which will be replaced based on the current environment (dev or production)

Answer (score 1):

OK, so I have installed webpack over npm. Additional I need some additional code in the `vue.config.js`, correct? Now my `vue.config.js` is:

```
const { defineConfig } = require('@vue/cli-service')
module.exports = defineConfig({
  transpileDependencies: true,
  configureWebpack: {
    devServer: {
      proxy: {
        '/api': {
          target: 'http://localhost:3080',
},},},},})
```

And edit the Endpoint to `...app.post("/api/signup",async (req,res)=>{...` but its not work.

I get this error: `Proxy error: Could not proxy request` /api/signup `from localhost:8080 to http://localhost:3080 (ECONNREFUSED).`